# Listing parts horizontally in the exam document class

Tags: exam

Right now, I have the following code that compiles to look as shown:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
For each solid, calculate:

\begin{subparts}
    \subpart
    the volume

    \subpart
    the surface area
\end{subparts}

\begin{parts}
    \part
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \draw[thick] (-1.5,-0.5) coordinate (v4) {} -- (-1.5,-1.5) coordinate (v3) {} -- node[below] {$20$ m} (3.5,-1.5) coordinate (v6) {} -- node[right] {$8$ m} (3.5,1) coordinate (v5) {} -- cycle;
            \draw[thick] (-3.5,-1) coordinate (v1) {} -- node[left] {$3$ m} (-3.5,0) -- (1.5,1.5) coordinate (v2) {};
            \draw[dashed, thick] (v1) -- (1.5,-1) coordinate (v7) {} -- (v2);
            \draw[thick] (v3) -- node[below left] {$5$ m} (v1);
            \draw[thick] (v4) -- (-3.5,0);
            \draw[thick] (v5) -- (1.5,1.5);
            \draw[dashed, thick] (v6) -- (v7);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \part
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
             \draw[thick] (-1.5,-1.5) arc (180:-60:1.5cm and 0.6cm) coordinate (t);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- (t);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- (-1.5,-1.5);
             \draw[thick, dashed] (-1.5,-5) arc (180:0:1.5cm and 0.6cm);
             \draw[thick] (1.5,-5) arc (0:-60:1.5cm and 0.6cm) coordinate (b);
             \draw[thick] (0,-5) -- (b);
             \draw[thick] (0,-5) -- node [below] {$5$ cm} (-1.5,-5);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (-1.5,-1.5) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.5) -- node [right] {$12$ cm} ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (t) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (-0.25,-1.5) arc (180:-60:0.25cm and 0.1cm) node [above right] {$240 \degree$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: exam layout before]

However, I'd like to list subparts i. and ii. and parts (a) and (b) on the same line, so that it looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
For each solid, calculate:

\begin{subparts}

    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \subpart
    the volume
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \subpart
    the surface area
    \end{minipage}
\end{subparts}

\begin{parts}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \part
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
            \draw[thick] (-1.5,-0.5) coordinate (v4) {} -- (-1.5,-1.5) coordinate (v3) {} -- node[below] {$20$ m} (3.5,-1.5) coordinate (v6) {} -- node[right] {$8$ m} (3.5,1) coordinate (v5) {} -- cycle;
            \draw[thick] (-3.5,-1) coordinate (v1) {} -- node[left] {$3$ m} (-3.5,0) -- (1.5,1.5) coordinate (v2) {};
            \draw[dashed, thick] (v1) -- (1.5,-1) coordinate (v7) {} -- (v2);
            \draw[thick] (v3) -- node[below left] {$5$ m} (v1);
            \draw[thick] (v4) -- (-3.5,0);
            \draw[thick] (v5) -- (1.5,1.5);
            \draw[dashed, thick] (v6) -- (v7);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \part
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
             \draw[thick] (-1.5,-1.5) arc (180:-60:1.5cm and 0.6cm) coordinate (t);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- (t);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- (-1.5,-1.5);
             \draw[thick, dashed] (-1.5,-5) arc (180:0:1.5cm and 0.6cm);
             \draw[thick] (1.5,-5) arc (0:-60:1.5cm and 0.6cm) coordinate (b);
             \draw[thick] (0,-5) -- (b);
             \draw[thick] (0,-5) -- node [below] {$5$ cm} (-1.5,-5);
             \draw[thick] (0,-1.5) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (-1.5,-1.5) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.5) -- node [right] {$12$ cm} ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (t) -- ++(0,-3.5);
             \draw[thick] (-0.25,-1.5) arc (180:-60:0.25cm and 0.1cm) node [above right] {$240 \degree$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have reduced the size of first picture using `,x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm` in the `tikzpicture` options so that things fit in properly..