# Using the exam document class, how to get multiple question parts on the same line?

Tags: exam, parts, line

Using the `parts` environment of the `exam` document class, I want to have multiple parts of a question on the same line. The default `\part` puts each part on a separate line.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\boxedpoints
\begin{parts}
\part[10] $p\vee q$
\part[10] $\neg p \wedge q$
\part[10] $\neg q\vee (\neg p \wedge q)$
\end{parts}
\end{document}
```

like so.
[image]

But I want something like
[image: parts on a line]
with the score for each part alongside its label.

How can I get that?

Comment: One could fake it using \fullwidth, but one would really need to dig into the code to see how to make it compatible wrt points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easy way is using the multicol package:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Then you can start the columns before your parts and end them afterwards:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\boxedpoints
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{parts}
\part[10] $p\vee q$
\part[10] $\neg p \wedge q$
\part[10] $\neg q\vee (\neg p \wedge q)$
\end{parts}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by putting each part in a minipage and manually adjusting the counter for the part numbers:

```
\begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
\begin{parts}
\part[10] $p\vee q$
\end{parts}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
\begin{parts}
\setcounter{partno}{1}
\part[10] $\neg p \wedge q$
\end{parts}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
\begin{parts}
\setcounter{partno}{2}
\part[10] $\neg q\vee (\neg p \wedge q)$
\end{parts}
\end{minipage}
```

This would be awkward if you wanted to typeset a whole bunch of multipart problems, but it works if you have just one or two.

Comment: Manually adjusting the counter will be cumbersome. If I need to reorder the parts, I will have to readjust the counters as well.

Comment: With this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272293/listing-parts-horizontally-in-the-exam-document-class it is not necessary to adjust the counter. Just make the `minipage` enclose each `part`, not the whole `parts` environment.